# IPv6 not working on VMs created using multipass

Tags: networking, virtualization, ipv6, multipass

Commands issued on the VM:

```
$ ping -6 api6.ipify.org
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

$ ifconfig ens3
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.140.84.221  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.140.84.255
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe6c:abbe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:6c:ab:be  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 566497  bytes 327455872 (327.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 458879  bytes 57257695 (57.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ uname -a
Linux k3s 5.4.0-125-generic #141-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 10 13:42:03 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

On the host, IPv6 works.
Commands issued on the host:

```
$ ping -6 api6.ipify.org
PING api6.ipify.org(2607:f2d8:4010:8::2 (2607:f2d8:4010:8::2)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2607:f2d8:4010:8::2 (2607:f2d8:4010:8::2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=253 ms
64 bytes from 2607:f2d8:4010:8::2 (2607:f2d8:4010:8::2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=305 ms
64 bytes from 2607:f2d8:4010:8::2 (2607:f2d8:4010:8::2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=252 ms

$ uname -a
Linux ThinkPad 5.19.5-051905-generic #202208291036 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Aug 29 10:47:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

How to make IPv6 work on the VM? I expected this to either work out of the box or there to be some command line option in multipass but could not find one.

Answer (score 1):

Multipass uses a separate network between client and host called mpqemubr0 (you may have a different interface name). This network does not provide IPv6 info via dhcpdv6 or radvd (or both).
Your IPv6 routing table can be seen with `ip -6 route show`
Guess your client does not have a default route for IPv6.

Your Options:

1. Add radvd/dhcpdv6 to the host providing IPV6 Info on the Multipass interface. Your host acts as a IPv6 router, maybe you will need some more ip6tables rules for masquerading, IPv6 forwarding must be enabled
2. Change the type on the multipass interface towards a bridged network instead of routing. See Multipass documentation
3. Switch to docker if your use case allows it, even here IPv6 does not work out of the box, but it much faster